# liquibase : execute a changeset each time I run the application

Tags: liquibase

I am using liquibase to load data in my Mysql database like this :

```
<loadUpdateData encoding="UTF-8"
          primaryKey="pk_id"
          file="config/liquibase/site.csv"
          separator=";"
          tableName="site">
    <column name="site" type="STRING"/>
</loadUpdateData>
```

How can I force liquibase to execute this task each time I run my application (in case site.csv has changed)? My problem is that when liquibase has executed the changeset, it won't execute it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to run it if the CSV file has changed, add `runOnChange="true"` as an attribute to the to the `changeSet`.

```xml
<changeSet id="42" author="arthur" runOnChange="true">
  <loadUpdateData>
  ...
  </loadUpdateData>
</changeSet>
```

If you **always** want to run it, use `runAlways="true"` instead.

See the manual for more details: 
http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changeset.html